# Grep yyyy-mm from directories name

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, text-processing

Quick question, I have this `find` clauses that find my backup directories in my external hard drive.

```
pi@raspberrypi:/media/pi/WD/HS_BACKUP $ find . -depth -maxdepth 2 -type d -name "20*"
/media/pi/WD/HS_BACKUP/2019-12-26_22-30-01
/media/pi/WD/HS_BACKUP/2019-12-27_22-30-01
/media/pi/WD/HS_BACKUP/2020-01-29_23-00-02
/media/pi/WD/HS_BACKUP/2020-02-05_23-00-01
/media/pi/WD/HS_BACKUP/2020-02-12_23-00-01
/media/pi/WD/HS_BACKUP/2020-02-19_23-00-01
/media/pi/WD/HS_BACKUP/2020-02-26_23-00-01
```

I needed to grep `yyyy-mm` part of the directories (e. g. `2020-02`), the desirable result should be.

```
2019-12
2019-12
2020-01
2020-02
2020-02
2020-02
```

How would I do that ? I tried `awk` with `[/_]` as delimiter, but it doesn't do the job right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grep expression you need is:

```
find ... | egrep --only-matching '[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you you please try following. Haven't tested it since I don't have same directory structure like OP, should work but.

```
find . -depth -maxdepth 2 -type d -name "20*" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"} match($NF,/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}/){print substr($NF,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
```